# Augmented Dickey Fuller says it's okay. But is it really?

Tags: time-series, augmented-dickey-fuller

This is original sales data. The biggest spike occurs during winter holidays with a consequent customer inactivity around early January. My Augmented Dickey Fuller Unit Root test is quite significant (t-test=7.227), which means that there is no unit root and the time series are stationary. What worries me is this huge spike and the sharp fall afterwards. Are we okay with using this data as long as ADF says it's okay? Or should we do something about it? Any thoughts are appreciated....

[image]

Comment: ADF is not an omnibus test of all your model assumptions. It's not very sensitive to this kind of problem.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a very strange comment to make. Anyway, thanks for the input.

Comment: I would try the `dfgls` test, which is more powerful, or maybe `pperron`. I would also consider adding the trend option to all three commands since you seem to have a trend on the right. More broadly, it would help with the interpretation if you also showed exactly what you typed (number of lags, trend, drift, constant).

Comment: This is where substantive knowledge of the data becomes important: what _is_ the spike?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. By looking at the time frame, I speculate that this is pre- and post-holiday season. The sales begin to steadily increase around mid-October, and the spike occurs right before mid-November. The drop takes place on Dec 21-27 (people are not shopping, just celebrating and relaxing). Right now, this is just raw data. My goal is to generate accurate predictions day-to-day basis...